# Removing non printable characters from expect logs?

Tags: bash, expect, tr

How can I either strip the following character sequences from my files? `^[[64;8H`, `^[[?25h`, `^[[1;64r` etc or avoid having expect add them in the first place?

*Background:*

I'm using a collection of expect scripts for certain tasks.

The output files I'm collecting often contain the above type of characters (as displayed in emacs / vi / cat -v). I've tried a number of tr commands like the following but it only makes the [64;8H etc visible.

```
tr -dc '[:print:]\n' < input
```

EDIT:

The results from above on a problematic line

```
[1;64r[64;1H[64;1H[2K[64;1H[?25h[64;1H[64;.....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close. You want

```
tr -dc '[:print:]\n' <input
```

From the `tr(1)` man page:

> **-c, -C, --complement**
>                use the complement of SET1

**Update**

If you want to remove escape sequences as well, you can use the following `sed` snippet:

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
```

It's taken from a serverfault question called [In CentOS 4.4, how can I strip escape sequences from a text file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/71285/in-centos-4-4-how-can-i-strip-escape-sequences-from-a-text-file)

Comment: Thanks Joseph. That makes the characters visible but doesn't strip them. I'll show the results in the question body.

Comment: @TimBrigham Does the update help?

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation (I use the fish shell, which colourizes everything):

```
perl -pe '
    s/\033\\\\\[(\d+;)*\d*[[:alpha:]]//g;
    s/\033\\\\\]0;//g;
    s/\x7//g;
    s/\033\(B//g;
' expect.log
```